# How to replace string in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have some string like

```
C:\dev\deploy_test.log
```

I want by means of Groovy to convert string to

```
C:/dev/deploy_test.log
```

I try to perform it with command

```
Change_1 = Log_file_1.replaceAll('\','/');
```

It doesn't convert this string

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash `\`:

```
println yourString.replace("\\", "/")
```

Comment: I am using like,   uname1 = uname.replace('@','%40') 
But getting error in jenkins pipeline..

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.util.Secret.replace() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Can you help

Comment: @SuryaN Looks like you're trying to call this method on a credential value. Pipeline casts credentials in a class hudson.util.Secret, which doesn't have this method. 
You can get a String object from Secret by calling getPlainText() method on it.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Groovy's [slashy string](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_slashy_string), which helps reduce the clutter of Java's escape character `\` requirements. In this case, you would use:

`Change_1 = Log_file_1.replaceAll(/\/,'/');`

Slashy strings also support interpolation, and can be multi-line. They're a great tool to add to your expertise.

##### References

- [Groovy's syntax documentation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html)
- [Baeldung's Groovy strings documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-strings#slashy-string)